# Sphinx doctest fails while exactly the same for Got and Expected

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, doctest

I got this fail report:

```
Document: readme
----------------
**********************************************************************
File "readme.rst", line ?, in default
Failed example:
    a
Expected:
    array(['Joe', 'Jane'],
          dtype='<U4')
Got:
    array(['Joe', 'Jane'],
          dtype='<U4')
**********************************************************************
```

There is a number of questions like this:

- [Doctest returning failure, yet "Expected" and "Got" match perfectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38678709/doctest-returning-failure-yet-expected-and-got-match-perfectly)
- [python doctest: expected result is the same as the "got" result but the test failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856502/python-doctest-expected-result-is-the-same-as-the-got-result-but-the-test-fai)
- [Python doctest failed for equal "Expected" and "Got"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44174988/python-doctest-failed-for-equal-expected-and-got?rq=1)

They all suggest looking for 'hidden' characters or spaces.

My reStructuredText looks like this:

```
test1:

    >>> a = np.array(['Joe', 'Jane'])
    >>> a
    array(['Joe', 'Jane'],
          dtype='<U4')

test2:

    >>> b = np.array([1,2,3])
    >>> b
    array([1, 2, 3])
```

test2 ran just fine.

I ran the code in a python command line and copy-pasted the result in the reStructuredtext, yet get this error. I copied the text from the fail report and pasted it back in a python string and compared with a==b (got True). I have many other examples in the same file that doctest just fine.

What can the hidden character possibly be and how do I get rid of it? What else can I do to figure where the problem is?

Is the there maybe something specific about numpy arrays?

I'd think this example is simple enough that other people must have stumbled on it...

Comment: Cannot reproduce using Python 3.7, Sphinx 1.7.7, numpy 1.14.3. What about replacing `>>> a` with `>>> a # doctest: +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE`?

Comment: @hoefling that works, as does ` # doctest: +SKIP `. I'm using python 3.6.4, Sphinx 1.7.6 and numpy 1.12.1. Maybe its because I use `.. include:: ../../README.rst` and the problem is inside the README.rst file? Or maybe its because of one of the sphinx plugins: 'sphinx.ext.autodoc', 'sphinx.ext.doctest', 'sphinx.ext.napoleon', 'sphinx.ext.autosectionlabel' that I use,..

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?